# How to create a module to process AJAX request?

Tags: 7, hooks, ajax

I want to create a module to process some AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/?q=mymodule/path',
    dataType:'json',
    type:'POST',
    data:{'key':'abc', 'value':'123'},
    success:function(data){
        /*do somthing*/
    },
    error:function(){
        /*do somthing*/
    }
});
```

So which hook function should I implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are tying your functionality to Drupal, use [Ajax framework commands](http://drupal.org/project/services)
.

If you want to process any arbitrary incoming request, (ajax or otherwise) implement a [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) resource.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
var element_settings = {};
element_settings.url = $(this).attr('href');
element_settings.event = 'click';
element_settings.progress = {
  type: 'throbber',
  message: ''
};
var base = $(this).attr('id');
Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax( base, this, element_settings );
```

Then use the [AJAX framework commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7) in your page callback to pass instructions back to Javascript.